# Can sp_whoisactive show execution plans on Azure SQL Database Hyperscale?

Tags: azure-sql-database

My new client is running their database in Azure SQL Database Hyperscale. 
I'm running

```
EXEC dbo.sp_WhoIsActive @get_plans=1
```

and normally I would get most execution plans, but on this system it is always NULL. 
Is this a "feature", or is there anything I can do to see the plans?

note:
At https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/6381/sql-server-sysdmexecqueryplan-query-plan-is-null/ I found

```
SELECT
   s.program_name, r.session_id, t.text, q.query_plan, r.plan_handle, r.sql_handle
FROM sys.dm_exec_requests r
JOIN sys.dm_exec_sessions s
ON r.session_id = s.session_id
CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_query_plan(r.plan_handle) q
CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(r.sql_handle) t
WHERE
   s.is_user_process = 1
```

That works. So the data is present, it is just that sp_whoisactive is not able to find the data.

Comment: I just tried it on a test hyperscale instance that I recently provisioned and can see the execution plan for a concurrent test query fine. It gets it from `sys.dm_exec_query_statistics_xml` though so see permissions https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/sys-dm-exec-query-statistics-xml-transact-sql?view=azuresqldb-current#permissions (I am AAD admin on that test instance)

Comment: @MartinSmith; That may explain it. I'm not an AAD admin, I think. But why is there a difference between the results from sys.dm_exec_query_statistics_xml and sys.dm_exec_query_plan?

Comment: `sys.dm_exec_query_statistics_xml` is the "live" execution plan and contains actual row counts of the currently executing plan. Maybe it is supposed to fall back to something else if unavailable but this was the plan I saw anyway. But the code is freely available anyway so you should be able to see what is querying and why it returns no results for you